# Confluent Control Centre not starting for Confluent version 7.0.1

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-control-center

I've done my best to follow this [website](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/installing_cp/zip-tar.html) tutorial to locally install Kafka on my MacBook Pro M1 Max then run it using the command:

 `arch -x86_64 confluent local services start`.
Every time I start it up, I get random funny errors on Control centre not starting even after modifying the following line in the control-center-production.properties file:

```
confluent.controlcenter.internal.topics.replication=1
confluent.controlcenter.command.topic.replication=1
confluent.monitoring.interceptor.topic.replication=1
confluent.metrics.topic.replication=1
```

These have been updated because I'm currently only running one Kafka broker on my local machine.
The error I now have is as shown below:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1 (file:/Users/samuelifere/Documents/Tutorials/Udemy/Kafka/confluent-7.0.1/share/java/acl/acl-7.0.1.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[2022-01-07 12:05:21,790] INFO [main] Capturing metrics for topic names _confluent-monitoring _confluent-metrics (io.confluent.controlcenter.streams.WindowExtractor)
[2022-01-07 12:05:21,792] INFO [main] transformerStore=MonitoringVerifierStore (io.confluent.controlcenter.streams.StreamsModule)
[2022-01-07 12:05:21,793] INFO [main] transformerStore=MonitoringTriggerStore (io.confluent.controlcenter.streams.StreamsModule)
[2022-01-07 12:05:21,793] INFO [main] transformerStore=TriggerActionsStore (io.confluent.controlcenter.streams.StreamsModule)
[2022-01-07 12:05:21,793] INFO [main] transformerStore=TriggerEventsStore (io.confluent.controlcenter.streams.StreamsModule)
[2022-01-07 12:05:21,793] INFO [main] transformerStore=AlertHistoryStore (io.confluent.controlcenter.streams.StreamsModule)
Exception in thread "main" com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) Error in custom provider, java.io.IOException: Unable to create parent directories of /var/lib/confluent/control-center/1/kafka-streams
  at io.confluent.controlcenter.streams.StreamsConfigModule.getStreamsStateDir(StreamsConfigModule.java:142) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> io.confluent.controlcenter.streams.StreamsConfigModule)
  while locating java.nio.file.Path annotated with @io.confluent.controlcenter.streams.StreamsConfigModule$StreamsStateDir()
    for the 4th parameter of io.confluent.controlcenter.streams.StreamsConfigModule.provideMonitoringStreamsConfig(StreamsConfigModule.java:56)
  at io.confluent.controlcenter.streams.StreamsConfigModule.provideMonitoringStreamsConfig(StreamsConfigModule.java:56) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> io.confluent.controlcenter.streams.StreamsConfigModule)
  while locating org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig
    for the 2nd parameter of io.confluent.controlcenter.streams.StreamsModule.provideMonitoringHeartbeatSender(StreamsModule.java:406)
  at io.confluent.controlcenter.streams.StreamsModule.provideMonitoringHeartbeatSender(StreamsModule.java:406) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> io.confluent.controlcenter.streams.StreamsModule)
  while locating io.confluent.controlcenter.streams.verify.MonitoringHeartbeatSender
    for the 5th parameter of io.confluent.controlcenter.streams.StreamsModule.provideVerifyTransformerSupplier(StreamsModule.java:290)
  at io.confluent.controlcenter.streams.StreamsModule.provideVerifyTransformerSupplier(StreamsModule.java:290) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> io.confluent.controlcenter.streams.StreamsModule)
  while locating io.confluent.controlcenter.streams.verify.VerifyTransformerSupplier
    for the 5th parameter of io.confluent.controlcenter.streams.StreamBuilderProvider.<init>(StreamBuilderProvider.java:219)
  while locating io.confluent.controlcenter.streams.StreamBuilderProvider
  at io.confluent.controlcenter.streams.StreamsModule.configure(StreamsModule.java:109) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> io.confluent.controlcenter.streams.StreamsModule)
  while locating io.confluent.controlcenter.streams.C3Streams$Builder

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:543)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:186)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:109)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:87)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:69)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:59)
    at io.confluent.controlcenter.util.InjectorFactory.createInjectorHelper(InjectorFactory.java:109)
    at io.confluent.controlcenter.util.InjectorFactory.createInjectorForApplication(InjectorFactory.java:65)
    at io.confluent.controlcenter.application.ControlCenter.setInjector(ControlCenter.java:156)
    at io.confluent.controlcenter.application.ControlCenter.run(ControlCenter.java:69)
    at io.confluent.controlcenter.ControlCenter.main(ControlCenter.java:46)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to create parent directories of /var/lib/confluent/control-center/1/kafka-streams
    at com.google.common.io.Files.createParentDirs(Files.java:485)
    at io.confluent.controlcenter.streams.StreamsConfigModule.getStreamsStateDir(StreamsConfigModule.java:147)
    at io.confluent.controlcenter.streams.StreamsConfigModule$$FastClassByGuice$$35c672b2.invoke(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod$FastClassProviderMethod.doProvision(ProviderMethod.java:264)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.doProvision(ProviderMethod.java:173)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl$CyclicFactory.provision(InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl.java:185)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl$CyclicFactory.get(InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl.java:162)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.doProvision(ProviderMethod.java:173)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl$CyclicFactory.provision(InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl.java:185)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl$CyclicFactory.get(InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl.java:162)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:148)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:39)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.doProvision(ProviderMethod.java:173)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl$CyclicFactory.provision(InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl.java:185)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl$CyclicFactory.get(InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl.java:162)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:148)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:39)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.doProvision(ProviderMethod.java:173)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl$CyclicFactory.provision(InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl.java:185)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl$CyclicFactory.get(InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl.java:162)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:148)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:39)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:113)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:91)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:306)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.get(BoundProviderFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:148)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:39)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.loadEagerSingletons(InternalInjectorCreator.java:211)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:182)
    ... 9 more
```

Please, any help would be much appreciated!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) I dont think Confluent support M1 via binary emulation, or otherwise; emulating a x86 Docker envirionment might be better 2) Sounds like a file permissions issue around `/var/lib/confluent/control-center`

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I followed a YouTube tutorial which showed it worked but the person didn't show how they configured the control center in the tutorial actually. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_u_aWbm-ZJ0

Answer (score 0):

Based on the video that you showed in the comments, you need to enable the Rosetta terminal; this will properly emulate the x64 environment for all the binaries, not only the `confluent` command. After you enable the Rosetta feature, then you don't need to use `arch -x86_64`

Also, note that the video is using Confluent Platform 6.0.1, and there may be differences with 7.0.1

[image]

Comment: I've just tested the same 6.0.1 version as the video and still didn't get it to work. All other services are up though same for the 7.0.1. I guess I'll have to just make do with those except someone is able to help out. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think the version is the problem. For example, run `zookeeper-server-start` and `kafka-server-start` manually. Don't run control center if you don't need it. It can always run emulated in Docker, if you need

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer! I've chosen to use ``brew`` to install it which has support for both jdk 17 and arm, so no need for the long process of emulation etc.

Comment: `brew install apache-kafka` would download the same binaries as downloading Confluent Platform (at least for Kafka/Zookeeper), but glad to hear